# How to unbrick galaxy grand 2

Tags: unbricking

I want to unbrick my galaxy grand 2 but instead of flashing the stock rom through odin, is there any other way to flash a custom rom instead?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Odin the stock ROM to get everything back to normal (you may need to use the appropriate PIT file to repartition), and then afterward you can flash a custom ROM as you would normally.